Tunnelmole stuck after command is set
I've been using tunnelmole happily for a day, but now it gets stuck in my cmd, I run tmole <port> but nothing prompts out, despite that the cmd tab changes its name to tunnelmole, it gets stuck there forever. As there is no error prompting I have no clue on what's going on.
It has been installed through npm.

I've also tried the curl installation but no change in output.
I've uninstalled from npm and installed again, nothing changes.
Tried different ports
Shutdown pc...


Robbie from Tunnelmole here.
I was not able to reproduce your issue as it was working for me when I tried it.
Nonetheless I took care of another issue I found in the logs that might have been responsible. I can't see anything wrong with how you're launching Tunnelmole.

I managed to solve the issue uninstalling and installing different times, finally its working, installing it via curl.
I still don't know why it broke the first time.
